# How can you remove the address bar in Firefox and still use it via command/control-l?

Tags: css, firefox

#### Some things I've tried

- [This extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fullscreen_plus/reviews/) disables the address bar in "fullscreen mode" (their own implementation), but 1) you can no longer access it 2) you have to re-enable it on every page and page reload.
- Adding `#navigator-toolbox {visibility: collapse;}` to `userChrome.css` disables the address bar, but this also disables most (all?) keybindings.

#### Question

Is there a solution that works everywhere, all the time, *and* still allows me to access the address bar when I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following CSS to your `userChrome.css`:

```css
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");

browser {
    margin-top: -30px;
}
```

This simply "hides" the area where the location/address bar normally appears.  You can still access it with control-l (or command-l).

However, you won't be able to see other menu items (e.g., addons overflow menu, profile menu, etc.). You can still access them via command-l tab (for page options), command-l tab tab (for addons overflow). This depends (how many tabs to hit) a bit on your personal setup, but the important thing is, they are still available.